# Reactive Forms Not Working with ControlValueAccessor

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I have built a control called `TextBox`, and for simplicity, I will only post the relevant parts of the control on here.

```js
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-textbox',
      template:
      `
        <input [(ngModel)]="value" [disabled]="disabled" />
      `,
      styleUrls: ['./textbox.component.css']
    })
    export class TextboxComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {
    
      constructor() { }
      writeValue(obj: any): void {
        this._value = obj;
      }
      registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
        this.onChange = fn;
      }
      registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
        this.onTouch = fn;
      }
      setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
        this.disabled = isDisabled;
      }
    
      disabled = false;
    
      onChange:()=>{}
      onTouch:()=>{};
    
      private _value:string;
      public get value():string {
        return this._value
      } 
      public set value(value:string){
        this._value = value;
      }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
      }
```

and my app.component.ts looks like:

```js
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      template:
      `
        <form [formGroup]="form" novalidate>
          <div>
            <label >Name</label>
            <app-textbox formControlName="name"></app-textbox>
          </div>
        </form>
      `,
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
      /**
       *
       */
      constructor(private formBuilder:FormBuilder) {
      }
    
      form = this.formBuilder.group({
        name:['', Validators.required]
      })
    
      model:NameModel = {
        name:'test'
      }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.form.get('name').setValue(this.model.name);
      }
    }
    
    interface NameModel{
      name:string;
    }
```

When I run the application I would expect that the textbox would be populated with the value test.

Can someone please explain why it is not?

I will add when I do `this.form.get('name')?.value` I get the correct value.

Comment: Try to move `this.form.get('name').setValue(this.model.name);` to `ngAfterViewInit` instead of `ngOnInit`

Comment: thank you @AmerYousuf that was the anwser. if you add that to the anwser, i will accept it.

Comment: Thanks, I added my answer with some notes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to move setting the value `this.form.get('name').setValue(this.model.name);` to `ngAfterViewInit` instead of `ngOnInit`, or you have to call after it:

```js
this.form.updateValueAndValidity();
```

Btw, there are two notes here you should take care of them:

1. You missed writing the value back to the form-control after it has been changed in your `TextboxComponent`, so you have to call the registered `onChange` method within the value setter like the following:

```js
private _value: string;
public get value(): string {
  return this._value;
}
public set value(value: string) {
  this._value = value;
  this.onChange(value);
}
```

2. It's better in your case to initialize the `FormGroup` within the `ngOnInit`, and set the default value of `name` directly, like the following:

```js
form: FormGroup;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    name: [this.model.name, Validators.required],
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `writeValue(obj)`, you need to assign received input `obj` to `this._value`

```js
writeValue(obj: any): void {
  if (obj !== this._value) {
    this._value = obj;
  }
}
```

And don't forget to add providers for `NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR` and the multi-provider to extend existing providers. *(Refer to References [1](https://almerosteyn.com/2016/04/linkup-custom-control-to-ngcontrol-ngmodel))*

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-textbox',
  template: `
    <input [(ngModel)]="value" [disabled]="disabled" />
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./textbox.component.css'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => TextboxComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class TextboxComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {

  writeValue(obj: any): void {
    if (obj !== this.value) {
      this._value = obj;
    }
  }

  ...
}
```

[Sample Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ejp9yl?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftextbox%2Ftextbox.component.ts)

---

### References

[Connect your custom control to ngModel with Control Value Accessor.](https://almerosteyn.com/2016/04/linkup-custom-control-to-ngcontrol-ngmodel)